# Laravel functionality that always runs

Tags: laravel, constructor

I was wondering if laravel has a function or constructor that always runs on all files.

I want to use this function (if it exist) to make the administrator logged in at all times while I am developing.

```
public function runsAlways()
{ 
   Auth::loginUsingId(1);
}
```

Comment: You can try middlewares

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `boot` function in the [`AppServiceProvider`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php) will be executed on every request.

But adding [a custom provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers) or [a middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware) to all your routes would be a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the default for authentication to last for longer example two weekes , you can adjust the session lifetime in the `session.php` config file.

```
'lifetime' => 20160, // 60 * 24 * 14
```

And log in user on boot method as @Jerodev mentioned